# Contact Form 7 is not working when submitting for the first time but it works fine when second time sumbit button is pressed

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7

**Contact Form 7 - WordPress - Contact form 7 is not working for the first time when it is submitted but when I submits the same form second time it works fine.
Error occurred for the first time is "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."**

Comment: You need to give more information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Exactly the same error here... any solutions to this?

Comment: Are you using browser private window? only this problem came in private window

Answer (score 0):

It seems to check the invisible recaptcha first and on success, halt any further events (ie checking the form validation and submitting).

```
((null !== cf7SubmitElm) && (typeof jQuery != 'undefined')) ? jQuery(frm).submit() : HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(frm);

to

((null !== cf7SubmitElm) && (typeof jQuery != 'undefined')) ? jQuery(cf7SubmitElm).trigger('click') : HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(frm);
```

in file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pakulska/wp-content/plugins/invisible-recaptcha/engine/PublicEngine.php around line 78.